# Prove that $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}(-1)^i\binom{M}{i+1}\frac{1}{1+ix\Delta}$ increases with $x$?

Tags: monotone-functions

How to prove that $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}(-1)^i\binom{M}{i+1}\frac{1}{1+ix\Delta}$, where $\Delta>0,M>1$, increases  with   $x$?

Comment: The term with $i=0$ is constant, so it does not affect increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define $\varphi$ by

$$ \varphi(u) = \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M}{i+1} u^i. $$

By a simple computation

$$ \varphi(u)
= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M-1}{i} \frac{M}{i+1} u^i
= \int_{0}^{1} M(1 - su)^{M-1} \, ds, $$

we find that $\varphi(u)$ decreases on $[0, 1]$. And this function is related to our $f$ by

$$
f(x)
= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M}{i+1} \frac{1}{1+ix\Delta}
= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M}{i+1} \int_{0}^{1} t^{ix\Delta} \, dt
= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(t^{x\Delta}) \, dt.
$$

Since $x \mapsto t^{x\Delta}$ decreases for each $t \in (0, 1)$, it follows that $x \mapsto \varphi(t^{x\Delta})$ increases. Therefore the claim follows.

---

*Proof of the 1<sup>st</sup> equality.* Notice that

$$ \binom{M}{i+1} = \binom{M-1}{i}\frac{M}{i+1} \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{0}^{1} s^{i} \, ds = \frac{1}{i+1}. $$

Then

\begin{align*}
\varphi(u)
&= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M-1}{i} \frac{M}{i+1} u^i \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M-1}{i} M u^i \int_{0}^{1} s^{i} \, ds \\
&= M \int_{0}^{1} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M-1}{i} u^i s^{i} \right) \, ds \\
&= M \int_{0}^{1} (1 - su)^{M-1} \, ds,
\end{align*}

where in the last line we utilized the binomial theorem to simply the sum.

*Proof of the 2<sup>nd</sup> equality.* Again, we know that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} t^{ix\Delta} \, dt = \frac{1}{1+ix\Delta}. $$

So we have

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M}{i+1} \frac{1}{1+ix\Delta} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M}{i+1} \int_{0}^{1} t^{ix\Delta} \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M}{i+1} t^{ix\Delta} \right) \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(t^{x\Delta}) \, dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: Interesting! But why this equality holds? $$ \varphi(u)
= \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} (-1)^i \binom{M-1}{i} \frac{M}{i+1} u^i
= \int_{0}^{1} M(1 - su)^{M-1} \, ds, $$

Comment: @Dave, The first equality follows from $$ \binom{M}{i+1} = \frac{M}{i+1}\binom{M-1}{i}, $$ and the second identity follows from the identity $$\int_{0}^{1} s^{i} \, ds = \frac{1}{1+i} $$ combined with the binomial theorem. :)

Comment: Dear @ Sangchul Lee,  I check the equality you give using matlab, and it is correct from the numerical results.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee But I am still not very clear that where is the $\sum$ in the second identity?

Comment: @Dave, I added some extra explanation.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee, Thank you very much for your kindly comments on my question.

Comment: Dear @ Sangchul Lee, if $\frac{1}{1+ix\Delta}$ is replaced by some more general form such as $\frac{x}{a_ix+b_i}$ with $a_i,b_i>0$, can you have some method to handle this? Thank you!

Comment: @Dave, My understanding on this particular case is that it is related to the iterated forward difference applied to a completely monotone function. For general $a_i$ and $b_i$, though, there is no reason for the same thing to hold. For instance, you can play with $a_i$ and $b_i$ to replicate marty cohen's mistaken example.

Comment: Thank you, @ Sangchul Lee. Would you please explain more on how can I apply the iterated forward difference into the general form function.

Comment: @Dave, I know not much about that topic. But a general idea is that if your sequence came from some nice function, then the $n$-fold finite difference will approximate the $n$-th derivative. Of course, this is rather a naive intuition rather than an established fact, so any specific claim should be justified case by case. This is almost all I know about it, so you may google it for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that
it's true.

For
$m=3$
with $\delta = 1$,
$f(x)
=1-\dfrac{3}{1+x}+\dfrac{3}{1+2x}
=1-3\dfrac{1+2x-(1+x)}{(1+x)(1+2x)}
=1-3\dfrac{x}{(1+x)(1+2x)}
$.

If
$g(x)
=\dfrac{x}{(1+x)(1+2x)}
$,
then,
according to Wolfy,
$g'(x)
=\dfrac{1 - 2 x^2}{(x + 1)^2 (2 x + 1)^2}
$
and this changes sign at
$1/\sqrt{2}$
so it is not monotonic.

Comment: If $M = 3$ and $\Delta = 1$, then $f(x)$ should be $$ f(x) = 3 - \frac{3}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1+2x}. $$ And this function is monotone increasing.